# Can't show proper error message after validation failure in Spring MVC

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, uiviewcontroller

I just started using spring MVC and unable to show proper error message on validation failure.

Controller is :

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/MobiusDashboardWebsiteContent/csiBatchSubmission", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @LogAction(actionPerformed = "submitCSIBatch")
        public String submitCSIBatch(ManualCSIBatch manualCSIBatch, BindingResult result, Model model, MobiusAuthenticationToken authToken) throws Throwable {

            ManualCSIBatch mBatch = new ManualCSIBatch();
            manualCSIBatch.setBatchUser(getUserName(authToken));
            csiBatchValidator.validate(manualCSIBatch, result);
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                 LOG.error("Validation errors found for the batch " + manualCSIBatch.getBatchName() + " error code is " + manualCSIBatch.getErrorCode());  
model.addAttribute("localeList", localeList);
            model.addAttribute("evaluateAttributeList", evaluateAttibutes);
            model.addAttribute("csiBatchSubmission", manualCSIBatch);                
return "csiBatchSubmission";
            }
            mBatch.setErrorCode(StatusCode.SUCESS.getCode());
            model.addAttribute("csiBatchSubmission", mBatch);
            return "csiBatchSubmission";
        }
```

Validator is:

```
   @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ManualCSIBatch manualCSIBatch = (ManualCSIBatch) target;
        boolean isDuplicate = getiMobiusService().checkDuplicateCSIBatchName(manualCSIBatch.getBatchName(), manualCSIBatch.getBatchUser());
        if (isDuplicate) {
            logger.debug("This is a duplicate batch " + manualCSIBatch.getBatchName() + " for this user " + manualCSIBatch.getBatchUser());
            errors.rejectValue("batchName", "errors.csi.duplicateBatch", new Object[] { manualCSIBatch.getBatchName() }, null);
        }
```

When validation fails, everything goes fine, form doesn't submit but error value is not being populated on the UI.

JSP is like this :

```
<div class="row">

    <label for="batch-name"><spring:message code="csi.label.batchname"/></label><form:input path="batchName" onkeyup="checkDuplciateBatch(this.value);" onblur="checkDuplciateBatch(this.value);"/> 
    <span id="availmsg" style="display:none"></span>
    <form:errors path="batchName" cssClass="error"/>
    </div>
```

In all the examples I saw, this is the way. What might be wrong in here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here we go.

I came to know that BindingResult is maped to each model attribute.

As per, http://blog.nigelsim.org/2011/09/07/spring-mvc-validation-bindingresult/ adding @ModelAttribute before Model object solved the problem!! Awesome! :)